# Unzip Files with arabic name programatically in android

Tags: java, android, zip, rar

I have android app that downloads compressed files and then decompress it ..

it works fine with English name files..

but if the file with Arabic name it make error malformated

```
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MALFORMED[1]
```

this is my code..

appreciate your help

Thanks

```
    private boolean unpackZip(String path, String zipname)
    {
        InputStream is;
        ZipInputStream zis;
        try
        {
            String filename;
            is = new FileInputStream(path + zipname);
            zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));
            ZipEntry ze;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int count;

            while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null)
            {
                filename = ze.getName();

                // Need to create directories if not exists, or
                // it will generate an Exception...
                if (ze.isDirectory()) {
                    File fmd = new File(path + filename);
                    fmd.mkdirs();
                    continue;
                }

                FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(path + filename);

                while ((count = zis.read(buffer)) != -1)
                {
                    fout.write(buffer, 0, count);
                }

                fout.close();
                zis.closeEntry();
            }

            zis.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is), Charset.forName("Windows-1256"));
```

as default is UTF-8 and that evidently did not work.

---

***After feedback:*** evidently there is some Android API version problem.

You could inspect:

```
filename = ze.getName();
```

Sometimes one can "patch" the encoding. Very error prone, or even not feasible.

```
filename = new String(filename.getBytes("..."), "...");
```

where one might try different encodings:

- Windows-1256
- UTF-8

(Especially converting *to* UTF-8 might raise conversion errors, as UTF-8 requires the bytes to have a specific bit pattern for multibyte sequences.)

Comment: Thanks for reply
but i face this error

Call requires API level 24 (current min is 16): new java.util.zip.ZipInputStream